# With CloudRig, How do I scale the controllers without changing the scale of the deformation bones?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, transforms

I've generated a rig with CloudRig. I've yet to parent it to the mesh because the FK Controllers are so large and cluttered, especially around the head area, where I have several bones for the hair. Does anyone know how I can make them smaller/more manageable?
[image: Cluttered Controllers only FK Turned on][image: Cluttered Controllers Secondary FK turned on][image: Scale Controller Scale Def. Bones]

Comment: Please don't post photos of your monitor screen. Blender has a built-in method to create screenshots via the Window > Save Screenshot menu.    We can only help with questions about Blender and its built-in addons here. While the CloudRig addon was produced by the Blender Studio team, no-one here has any association with the Blender Foundation and so your question is off -topic.

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you

Comment: for the generated animation rig you can scale down the shape of the control bones in the viewport display settings. Unfortunately, you need to do this every time after you re-generated the rig.

Comment: @Blunder Cash; I appreciate you!